# Method filter even value in array and return them in a new array

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

Could any one tell me how to correct following code to work correctly?

Write a method filterEvens which takes in an array of integers and returns a new array containing only the even values.

new array containing only the even values. Eg:

```
int[] data = {1, 3, 4, 2, 0, 5, -2};
int[] evens = filterEvens(data);

public static int[] filterEvent(int[] data) {
    int countLength = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] % 2 == 0) {
            countLength++; 
        }
    }

    int[] filArray = new int[countLength]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] % 2 == 0) {
            filArray[i] = data[i]; 
        }
    }

    return filArray;  
}
```

Comment: Step 1: format your code consistently and use whitespace properly. Will the counter of `filArray` and `data` be the same? They're not the same length, and will contain different items at different indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is:

```
for (int i =0; i< data.length;i++)
  {
    if(data[i]%2==0)
    {
      filArray[i]= data[i] ; 
    }
}
```

You're looping from values 0 --> data.length. That's an issue because the array filArray[i] is of a smaller length.

Imagine it like this, you're looking for someone's house. On the street they give you, let's say Emerald Dr. The house numbers can be from 2000 - 3000. Then you are told that they live at 4000 Emerald Dr. Same case here, except the computer is trying to find the house.

Answer (score 1):

you're filling the wrong index.

You have

```
if(data[i]%2==0)
{
  filArray[i]= data[i] ; 
}
```

which is correct for the cell of data but the cell of filArray is wrong change it to

```
 int j = 0; 
 for (int i =0; i< data.length;i++)
  {
    if(data[i]%2==0)
    {
      filArray[j]= data[i] ;
      j++; 
    }
  }
```

The rest looks OK. Though you should take a look at `ArrayList` as it would be able to make this more efficient

Comment: Or just do `filArray[j++] = data[i]`.

Comment: true but since he said he was new to java I wanted to keep it a little more simplistic.